# How to transfer data from Elasticsearch to SQLite?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, elasticsearch

For a Node.js project with Elasticsearch I have to change DBMS to SQLite. I choose [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/) ORM as a Node.js model.

I was able to create a new SQLite database and model, however I don't know how to convert the data stored with Elasticsearch to SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option would be to use Logstash, with JDBC as the output. For example:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://localhost:9200/"
    user => "yourUser"
    password => "yourPassword"
    index => "yourIndex"
    query => '{"query":{"match_all": {}}}'
    scroll => "5m"
    size => "5000"
  }
}

output {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => ""
    jdbc_user => ""
    jdbc_password => ""
    jdbc_validate_connection => true
    jdbc_driver_library => ""
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    statement => "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ... <<<<< JUST A QUERY EXAMPLE)"
  }
}
```